# FullCalendar desaparece si agrego otros elementos a la pagina

Tags: html, jquery, bootstrap, fullcalendar, adminlte

> Buenas, estoy un poco perdido, estoy tratando de hacer un módulo de turnos para el sistema de un amigo, y el siguiente código funciona correctamente:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {


    /* initialize the external events
       -----------------------------------------------------------------*/
    function ini_events(ele) {
        ele.each(function() {

            // create an Event Object (http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/Event_Object/)
            // it doesn't need to have a start or end
            var eventObject = {
                title: $.trim($(this).text()) // use the element's text as the event title
            }

            // store the Event Object in the DOM element so we can get to it later
            $(this).data('eventObject', eventObject)

            // make the event draggable using jQuery UI
            $(this).draggable({
                zIndex: 1070,
                revert: true, // will cause the event to go back to its
                revertDuration: 0 //  original position after the drag
            })

        })
    }

    ini_events($('#external-events div.external-event'))




    var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

    var d = new Date();

    var dia = d.getDate();
    var mes = d.getMonth() + 1;
    var ano = d.getFullYear();

    if (mes < 10) {
        var hoy = ano + "-0" + mes + "-" + dia;
    } else if (dia < 10) {
        var hoy = ano + "-" + mes + "-0" + dia;
    } else if (mes < 10 && dia < 10) {
        var hoy = ano + "-0" + mes + "-0" + dia;
    } else {
        var hoy = ano + "-" + mes + "-" + dia;
    }


    var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
        plugins: ['interaction', 'dayGrid', 'timeGrid'],
        defaultView: 'timeGridWeek',
        defaultDate: hoy,
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay'
        },
        businessHours: [ // specify an array instead
            {
                daysOfWeek: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
                startTime: '09:00', // 8am
                endTime: '21:00' // 6pm
            }
        ],
        minTime: "09:00",
        maxTime: "21:00",
        events: [{
            title: 'Agustin Guerra',
            start: '2020-02-27T10:30:00',
            end: '2020-02-27T11:30:00',
        }],

        editable: true,
        droppable: true, // this allows things to be dropped onto the calendar !!!
        drop: function(info) {
            // is the "remove after drop" checkbox checked?
            if (checkbox.checked) {
                // if so, remove the element from the "Draggable Events" list
                info.draggedEl.parentNode.removeChild(info.draggedEl);
            }
        }
    });




    calendar.render();

    /* ADDING EVENTS */
    var currColor = '#3c8dbc' //Red by default
        //Color chooser button
    var colorChooser = $('#color-chooser-btn')
    $('#color-chooser > li > a').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault()
            //Save color
        currColor = $(this).css('color')
            //Add color effect to button
        $('#add-new-event').css({
            'background-color': currColor,
            'border-color': currColor
        })
    })
    $('#add-new-event').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault()
            //Get value and make sure it is not null
        var val = $('#new-event').val()
        if (val.length == 0) {
            return
        }

        //Create events
        var event = $('<div />')
        event.css({
            'background-color': currColor,
            'border-color': currColor,
            'color': '#fff'
        }).addClass('external-event')
        event.html(val)
        $('#external-events').prepend(event)

        //Add draggable funtionality
        ini_events(event)

        //Remove event from text input
        $('#new-event').val('')
    })

    // initialize the external events
    // -----------------------------------------------------------------

    new Draggable(containerEl, {
        itemSelector: '.external-event',
        eventData: function(eventEl) {
            console.log(eventEl);
            return {
                title: eventEl.innerText,
                backgroundColor: window.getComputedStyle(eventEl, null).getPropertyValue('background-color'),
                borderColor: window.getComputedStyle(eventEl, null).getPropertyValue('background-color'),
                textColor: window.getComputedStyle(eventEl, null).getPropertyValue('color'),
            };
        }
    });

});
```

```html
<!-- Content Wrapper. Contains page content -->
<div class="content-wrapper">
    <!-- Content Header (Page header) -->
    <section class="content-header">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row mb-2">
          <div class="col-sm-6">
            <h1>Turnos</h1>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-6">
            <ol class="breadcrumb float-sm-right">
              <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="#">Inicio</a></li>
              <li class="breadcrumb-item active">Turnos</li>
            </ol>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </section>

    <!-- Main content -->
    <section class="content">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">


          <div class="col-9">
            <div class="card card-primary">
              <div class="card-body p-0">
                <!-- THE CALENDAR -->
                <div id="calendar"></div>
              </div>
              <!-- /.card-body -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.card -->
          </div>



          <!-- /.col -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.row -->
      </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </section>
    <!-- /.content -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.content-wrapper -->
```

> El javascript lo saqué de los ejemplos de la plantilla `adminLTE3` (Examples, calendar), no lo escribí yo.
>
> En el `html`, si yo lo dejo como está, el `div` con id `calendar` se renderiza correctamente, con la configuracion que yo deseo (le configuré las horas que quiero que se muestren, las que quiero que esten disponibles, como se va a mostrar al inicio, etc. Todo esto lo saque de la documentacion de `fullCalendar`)
>
> Ahora, yo deseo agregar una columna `col-3` de boostrap, donde quiero agregar unos `cards` para poder crear desde ellos el turno (coloco el nombre del mismo, le doy al boton `add` y ya puedo agarrar el turno creado y arrastrarlo adentro del calendario, en el dia y la hora que yo deseo. Este elemento ya esta creado tambien en el ejemplo de `adminLTE3`, y cuando lo agrego funciona correctamente. **El problema es que cuando este elemento de `col-3` se renderiza, el calendario desaparece.**

Este es el código del elemento que va a ocupar 3 columnas:

```
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="sticky-top mb-3">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header">
              <h4 class="card-title">Draggable Events</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
              <!-- the events -->
              <div id="external-events">
                <div class="external-event bg-success">Lunch</div>
                <div class="external-event bg-warning">Go home</div>
                <div class="external-event bg-info">Do homework</div>
                <div class="external-event bg-primary">Work on UI design</div>
                <div class="external-event bg-danger">Sleep tight</div>
                <div class="checkbox">
                  <label for="drop-remove">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="drop-remove">
                    remove after drop
                  </label>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /.card-body -->
          </div>
          <!-- /.card -->
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header">
              <h3 class="card-title">Create Event</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
              <div class="btn-group" style="width: 100%; margin-bottom: 10px;">
                <!--<button type="button" id="color-chooser-btn" class="btn btn-info btn-block dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Color <span class="caret"></span></button>-->
                <ul class="fc-color-picker" id="color-chooser">
                  <li><a class="text-primary" href="#"><i class="fas fa-square"></i></a></li>
                  <li><a class="text-warning" href="#"><i class="fas fa-square"></i></a></li>
                  <li><a class="text-success" href="#"><i class="fas fa-square"></i></a></li>
                  <li><a class="text-danger" href="#"><i class="fas fa-square"></i></a></li>
                  <li><a class="text-muted" href="#"><i class="fas fa-square"></i></a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
              <!-- /btn-group -->
              <div class="input-group">
                <input id="new-event" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Event Title">

                <div class="input-group-append">
                  <button id="add-new-event" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Add</button>
                </div>
                <!-- /btn-group -->
              </div>
              <!-- /input-group -->
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

> Dejo capturas por si no me hago entender:

[image: Resultado Esperado]

> **Resultado esperado**
>   [image: Lo que tengo]
>   **Lo que tengo**
>   [image: Lo que me sucede]
>   **Lo que me sucede**